# Sharing promotion letter from an old employer

Tags: resume, job-search, new-job, security

I am currently searching for a job. Can I include the promotion letter from my old employer in my portfolio? It includes words of appreciation, new designation, and allowance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should include all the details of your previous assignment and all written materials including your training & courses certificate with final grading (if you have any), evidence of all positive performance indicators like appreciation, award, promotion & bonus etc. All these attachments support you and increase your chances of selection.